# Contact Form spread out in Tabs

Tags: php, jquery, forms, contacts

i am trying to build a contact form that presents different fields on different tabs.
I have made it work so that i can have different fields inside a target div and the jquery makes it work so that different fields load but how could i go about making the form submit with just the visible form data available not take consideration of all the other fields.

Thanks to everyone i just need a bump to get on the right direction

Comment: This question is a little too ambiguous. It would be better for us (and you) to come up with a more concrete example and some code to work with.

Comment: Are you using jquery tabs to do the tabination?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myform').live('submit', function () {
    //gather the data you want to submit
    data = {
        'value1':$('selector').val()
    }
    $.post(url, data, i_get_run_when_done());
    //prevent the form from trying to submit the old fashioned way.
    e.preventDefault()
    return false;
}
```

If you want all the form fields in a div you could do something like

```
form_fields = $('container').find('input')
```

then you could iterate over it like

```
form_fields.each(function () {
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
}
```

or you could just detach all the elements that are not :visible before you submit.

```
$('#myform').live('submit', function () {
    items = $('input').not(':visible')
    items.detach()
    return items //now you have the items in order to reattach them if you chose to do so
}
```

In this case the form would submit itself, but you would have removed all the form fields that you didn't want submitted before the submit.

Comment: in this case i_get_run_when_done() could also be an anonymous function like in the event handler.  $.post(url, data, function () {//code here}